# Two cars travelling, find minimum distance given a ratio of speeds.

Tags: derivatives, inequality, optimization, kinematics

Here is a question from a Cambridge practice paper. Year 12 standard, math B. It involves finding the time when the cars are at a minimum distance from each other (part a). I have solved part a below. However, I am stuck on part b. A solution for part c would also be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Two straight roads cross at right angles at a point $X$. A red car travels at $v \: km/h$ along the first road away from $X$. A blue car travels at $w \: km/h$ along the other road towards $X$. At a particular time the red car is $a \: km$ from $X$ and the blue car is $b \: km$ from $X$. (Only consider positive values of $a$, $b$, $v$, $w$.)

**a.** If $a=b=100\:km$ and $w=100\:km/h$ and $v=80\:km/h$ determine the time, correct to the nearest minute when the cars are closest and determine their distance apart at this point, correct to the nearest meter.

**b.** Returning to the general situation: If $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{w}{v}$ show that the cars will be closest when their distances from $X$ are in the ratio $w:v$.

**c.** Given that $a=b=100\:km$ and that the cars are closest after 1 hour show that the pairs $(w, v)$ of possible values of $w$ and $v$ lie on an arc the circle $(v+50)^2+(w-50)^2=5000$ and verify $w=60$, $v=20$  is one such pair.

---

## Part A solution

Here, I am using $d$ as referring to the distance to point $X$. $r$ is red and $b$ is blue.

It is known that speed is given by $s=\frac{d}{t}$

Thus distance with respect to time can be given for both cars:

$$d_r=a+vt$$
$$d_b=b-wt$$

Since the roads are a right angles, pythagoras can be used to solve for the total distance $$d_t=\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}$$

In part a, values are given as follows: $a=b=100\:km$ and $w=100\:km/h$ and $v=80\:km/h$.

Therefore, $$d_t=\sqrt{(100+80t)^2+(100-100t)^2}$$

Now differentiate and solve for a minimum

$\frac{dd_t}{dt}=\frac{2\cdot 80(100+80t)-2\cdot 100(100-100t)}{2\sqrt{(100+80t)^2+(100-100t)^2}}$
$\frac{dd_t}{dt}=\frac{80(100+80t)-100(100-100t)}{\sqrt{(100+80t)^2+(100-100t)^2}}$
$0=80(100+80t)-100(100-100t),\:\:\:\: 0\neq (100+80t)^2+(100-100t)^2$

since the denominator cannot equal zero.

Thus:
$100(100-100t)=80(100+80t)$
$10000-10000t=8000+6400t$
$2000=16400t$
$t=0.1219512195$
$$\therefore t=7\:min, \:\:\:19.024\:sec$$

Substituting back in, that gives

$d_{t\: min}=\sqrt{(100+80(0.12195...))^2+(100-100(0.12195...))^2}$  *(carried decimal in calculator)*
$d_{t\: min}=140.556\:km$

---

## Attempted Part B

Not too hard. But how do I do part B? This is what I've tried so far:

I figured that with the inequality: $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{w}{v}$, perhaps I could find the double derivative and find when that is positive, since $\frac{d^2d}{dt^2}>0$ for a local minimum. However, it gets messy and I don't think I'm on the right track. Anyway, see what you think.

Starting with the general equation: $$d_t=\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}$$

Then differentiate it: $$\frac{dd_t}{dt}=\frac{2v(a+vt)-2w(b-wt)}{2\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}}$$
Simplify: $$\frac{dd_t}{dt}=\frac{va+v^2t-wb+w^2t}{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}}$$
And differentiate again: $$\frac{d^2d_t}{dt^2}=\frac{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}\cdot (v^2+w^2)-\frac{2v(a+vt)-2w(b-wt)}{2\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}}\cdot (va+v^2t-wb+w^2t)}{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}^2}$$
And now set it to be greater than zero: $$0<\frac{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}\cdot (v^2+w^2)-\frac{va+v^2t-wb+w^2t}{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}}\cdot (va+v^2t-wb+w^2t)}{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}$$
$$0<\frac{(v^2+w^2)\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}-\frac{(va+v^2t-wb+w^2t)^2}{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}}}{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}$$

Then
$$0[(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2]<(v^2+w^2)\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}-\frac{(va+v^2t-wb+w^2t)^2}{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}}$$
$$\frac{(va+v^2t-wb+w^2t)^2}{\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}}<(v^2+w^2)\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}$$
$$(va+v^2t-wb+w^2t)^2<(v^2+w^2)\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}\cdot \sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}$$
$$(va+v^2t-wb+w^2t)^2<(v^2+w^2)[(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2]$$
$$a^2v^2-2abvw+2atv^3+2atvw^2+b^2w^2-2btv^2w-2btw^3+t^2v^4+2t^2v^2w^2+t^2w^4<a^2v^2+a^2w^2+2atv^3+2atvw^2+b^2v^2+b^2w^2-2btv^2w-2btw^3+t^2v^4+2t^2v^2w^2+t^2w^4$$

This simplifies to: $$-2abvw<a^2w^2+b^2v^2$$
$$\frac{-2abvw}{ab}<\frac{a^2w^2}{ab}+\frac{b^2v^2}{ab}$$
$$-2vw<\frac{aw^2}{b}+\frac{bv^2}{a}$$

Just added more. Any ideas?

---

Any help for part c would also be welcome.

I hope I've been clear enough, but let me know if you need further clarification on anything.

Thanks all.

Hugo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the derivative likes what you did is overcomplicated. You can do the first and second parts it in a simple way:

**a**. $d_t=\sqrt{(100+80t)^2+(100-100t)^2}= \sqrt{16400t^2-2000t+20000}$. You can easily recognize that the square root gets the minimum value when the expression inside it gets the minimum value. So differentiating $16400t^2-2000t+20000$ now is much easier

**b**. $d_t=\sqrt{(a+vt)^2+(b-wt)^2}=\sqrt{(v^2+w^2)t^2+2(av-bw)t+a^2+b^2}$. Doing the same thing in part **a**, by differentiating the expression inside the square root, you will get $t=\dfrac {bw-av} {v^2+w^2}$. Now plug $t$ back in $a+vt$ and $b-wt$ and check the ratio

Comment: Legend. But how can I simplify $a+\frac{v[bw-av]}{v^2+w^2}$ and $b-\frac{w[bw-av]}{v^2+w^2}$
... before I plug it into $\frac{d_r}{d_b}$

Comment: @Hugs just write $a$ as $\dfrac{a(v^2+w^2)}{v^2+w^2}$ :))

Comment: Oh yep. So then it becomes $d_r=\frac{aw^2+bvw}{v^2+w^2}$ and $d_b=\frac{bv^2+vaw}{v^2+w^2}$

Comment: Any ideas for part C?

Comment: @Hugs You can replace $t = 1, a=b=100$ back into $t=\dfrac {bw-av} {v^2+w^2}$ and we are done. It is easy to do